# JavaScript: Priorizar valor em concatenação (.concat)

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou estudando sobre o concat e prioridades
O seguinte código atualmente concatena os valores dos texts no campo `ValFin`
Porém gostaria que se a prioridade do campo 4 (`Prival04` com o valor 1)  fosse menor do que a do campo 2 (`Prival02` com o valor 2), o campo 4 ordenasse primeiro

```js
function teste(){
  var a = document.getElementById('val01').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('val02').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('val03').value;
  var d = document.getElementById('val04').value;
  var f = a.concat(b).concat(c).concat(d);
  document.getElementById("ValFin").value = f;
  console.log(document.getElementById("ValFin").value);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Valor 01</label>
    <input id="val01" type="text" /> 
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 01</label>
    <input id="Prival01" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>    
    <label>Valor 02</label>
    <input id="val02" type="text" />
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 02</label>
    <input id="Prival02" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <label>Valor 03</label>
    <input id="val03" type="text" />
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 03</label>
    <input id="Prival03" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <label>Valor 04</label>
    <input id="val04" type="text" />    
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 04</label>
    <input id="Prival04" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <br>
    <button id="Calc" onclick="teste();">FuncaoMontar</button>
    <input id="ValFin" type="text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Terás de colocar as prioridades num array, ordenar e depois ter um ciclo que passa nesse array e vai buscar o valor daquela prioridade para concatenar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer ordenar conforme os campos de Prival certo?
Fiz um exemplo adicionando os valores em um array, onde você pode manipular de diversas formas...

Segue o exemplo:

```js
function teste(){
  var array = [];
  var a = {
    value: document.getElementById('val01').value,
    order: document.getElementById('Prival01').value
  };
  var b = {
    value: document.getElementById('val02').value,
    order: document.getElementById('Prival02').value
  };
  
  var c = {
    value: document.getElementById('val03').value,
    order: document.getElementById('Prival03').value
  };
  var d = {
    value: document.getElementById('val04').value,
    order: document.getElementById('Prival04').value
  };
  
// Adcionei os objetos no array
array.push(a, b, c, d);

// Utilizar o método sort para ordernar conforme o campo de ordenação
array.sort((a, b) => a.order < b.order ?  -1 : 1);
 
// Transoforma o array de objetos em um array de string e após faz o join para uma string sem espaços
var f = array.map(({value}) => value).join('');
  
document.getElementById("ValFin").value = f;
console.log(document.getElementById("ValFin").value);
}
```

```html
    <label>Valor 01</label>
    <input id="val01" type="text" /> 
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 01</label>
    <input id="Prival01" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>    
    <label>Valor 02</label>
    <input id="val02" type="text" />
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 02</label>
    <input id="Prival02" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <label>Valor 03</label>
    <input id="val03" type="text" />
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 03</label>
    <input id="Prival03" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <label>Valor 04</label>
    <input id="val04" type="text" />    
    <label>Prioridade do Valor 04</label>
    <input id="Prival04" type="text" maxlength="1" /> <br>
    <br>
    <button id="Calc" onclick="teste();">FuncaoMontar</button>
    <input id="ValFin" type="text" />
```

Comment: Exatamente !! Muito obrigado pela ajuda @André !!
Vou estudar o código aqui